# PyCharm debugger console ANSI escape sequences

Tags: pycharm, ansi-escape

PyChar 3.4.1 debugger console appears to support *some* ANSI escape sequences but not all. Is there a way to find out what is or isn't supported? I noticed that setting a text color like red '\033[31m' works but not the reset/normal/endc '\033[0m' code. I could set it to black but then I can't see the text on my black terminal window when I run the program from bash.

Also, I noted that stdin under the debugger returns False for

```
sys.stdin.isatty()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the code used by PyCharm for parsing ANSI escape sequences [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/execution/process/AnsiEscapeDecoder.java). (You can also send pull requests to add support for sequences which aren't supported by the current code.)