# Is there a python 3 command to clear the output console?

Tags: python-3.x, console, pycharm

So I am trying to make a simple Conway's game of life in PyCharm, and I can only get a a bunch outputs and not a video like stream in the output console. Is there a command that will let me clear the output every loop in the program. I have already tried the "sys" commands, and the ANSI escape keys (I hope I spelled that right). Nothing seems to be working! I am using Python 3.

I would like to clear the console on the first print statement in the while loop. If that helps.

```
import copy
import random
import time
WIDTH = 60
HEIGHT = 10


nextCells = []
for x in range(WIDTH):
    column = []
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            column.append('#')
        else:
            column.append(' ')
    nextCells.append(column)

while True:
    # print('\n\n\n\n')
    currentCells = copy.deepcopy(nextCells)

    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        for x in range(WIDTH):
            print(currentCells[x][y], end='')
        print()
```

Comment: Your code is all about game of life, and nothing about your "I have already tried the `sys` commands, and the ANSI escape keys (I hope I spelled that right). Nothing seems to be working!" Please show some _relevant_ code as your [example]. Also... are you using PyCharm console, or the normal terminal?

Comment: are you using the Python interpreter console to clear the output?

Comment: I am using the pycharm console. @Amadan

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502144/pycharm-debugger-console-ansi-escape-sequences), PyCharm console supports _some_ ANSI sequences, but is not really ANSI compatible, and doesn't implement any method you can hook into to clear it (besides the trivial "print a hundred newlines"). Complain to PyCharm devs. `os.system("clear")`, ANSI sequences etc should all work on a proper ANSI terminal, such as OSX terminal, Linux terminal... even Windows CMD terminal (with `cls` instead of `clear`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command prompt (not PyCharm console), try the `colorama` library to move the cursor back up and print the next iteration over the current iteration (`colorama` makes ANSI control codes compatible with Windows):

(`colorama` can be installed via `pip install colorama`)

```
import copy
import random
import time

import colorama
colorama.init()

WIDTH = 60
HEIGHT = 10

nextCells = []
for x in range(WIDTH):
    column = []
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            column.append('#')
        else:
            column.append(' ')
    nextCells.append(column)

while True:
    #print('\n\n\n\n')
    currentCells = copy.deepcopy(nextCells)

    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        for x in range(WIDTH):
            print(currentCells[x][y], end='')
        print()
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
            leftCoord = (x - 1) % WIDTH
            rightCoord = (x + 1) % WIDTH
            aboveCoord = (y - 1) % HEIGHT
            belowCoord = (y + 1) % HEIGHT

            numNeighbors = 0
            if currentCells[leftCoord][aboveCoord] == '#':
                numNeighbors += 1
            if currentCells[x][aboveCoord] == '#':
                numNeighbors += 1
            if currentCells[rightCoord][aboveCoord] == '#':
                numNeighbors += 1
            if currentCells[leftCoord][y] == '#':
                numNeighbors += 1
            if currentCells[rightCoord][y] == '#':
                numNeighbors += 1
            if currentCells[leftCoord][belowCoord] == '#':
                numNeighbors += 1
            if currentCells[x][belowCoord] == '#':
                numNeighbors += 1
            if currentCells[rightCoord][belowCoord] == '#':
                numNeighbors += 1

            if currentCells[x][y] == '#' and (numNeighbors == 2 or numNeighbors == 3):
                nextCells[x][y] = '#'
            elif currentCells[x][y] == ' ' and numNeighbors == 3:
                nextCells[x][y] = '#'
            else:
                nextCells[x][y] = ' '

    # Here we move the cursor back up:
    print(f'\033[{HEIGHT+1}A')

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: when i try that i get this error  ``` File "C:\Users\Carsten Brooks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'``` it pretty much is saying that i don't have the _curses module which is being called from the curses module __init__

Comment: Note that `curses` works by issuing ANSI control sequences, which PyCharm console does not know how to handle.

Comment: @SamChats Just tried it and it is doing the exact same thing.

Comment: What output is it giving? It's working correctly on my machine.

Comment: It gives me the same output but with a space in between every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Try using `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print()`.

Comment: I tried this earlier, but i tried it again and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work in the command prompt? Right now you're checking on PyCharm console right?

Comment: Yes it works! You where right @SamChats you have to execute in the terminal THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Glad to help you out! I've edited the answer; please accept it :)

Answer (score 4):

From this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/interactive-console.html.
It basically uses a system based python interpreter, there is no direct way or command to clear Python interpreter console. 
So you need a system call to clear the Python interpreter console screen. For window system, `cls` clear the console. For the Linux system, `clear` command works.
It requires the OS library to be imported.

`import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls') #on Windows System
os.system('clear') #on Linux System
clear()`

The “lambda” keyword in Python is used to define anonymous functions.

`import os` is inbuild in python 3

Comment: I tried doing that earlier but with no prevail, thanks though!

Comment: I found this question with google and @HariKishore suggestion does work.
For **PyCharm**  on Mac at least - You have to click on **Edit Configurations**  then select the current module from which you are running the code. 

Then check the checkbox labeled  **"Emulate terminal in output console"**  
Then, the os.system("clear") will work. 

It does look a bit off when it prints though. 
Give it a shot and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using vs code, then to clear the console output :

```
import os
    os.system('clear')
```